# Cannot handle multiple submit button when using Jquery .submit() - MVC 5

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Before this everything was working very well. I can handle multiple buttons in one action.

Here is my code snippet:

HTML

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AssignPlan", "Accounts", FormMethod.Post, new { @id= "formAssign", @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
    //Input
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="Command" value="Submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save" aria-hidden="true"></span> Assign Plan Only</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="Command" value="Approved"><span class="fa fa-check"></span> Assign Plan With Approved</button>
    </div>
}
```

Action

```
[HttpPost]      
public ActionResult AssignPlan(AssignPlanModel M, string Command)
{
    // my logic
}
```

Then I decide to use [ladda](http://lab.hakim.se/ladda/) loading button, then the problems started happening. My string `Command` always returns `NULL` on my action.

Here the modified code

HTML

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AssignPlan", "Accounts", FormMethod.Post, new { @id= "formAssign", @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
    // Input
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit"class="ladda-button btn btn-primary" data-style="zoom-in" name="Command" value="Submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save" aria-hidden="true"></span> Assign Plan Only</button>
        <button type="submit" class="ladda-button btn btn-primary" data-style="zoom-in" name="Command" value="Approved"><span class="fa fa-check"></span> Assign Plan With Approved</button>
    </div>
}
```

And I adding some jQuery script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#formAssign').submit(function () {
        if ($(this).valid()) {
            var val = document.activeElement.getAttribute('value');

            if(val == 'Approved')
            {                   
                var l = $('#BtnApp').ladda();

                l.ladda('start');

                $("#BtnSubmit").attr("disabled", true);
            }
            else
            {         
                var l = $('#BtnSubmit').ladda();

                l.ladda('start');

                $("#BtnApp").attr("disabled", true);
            }
        }
    })
});
</script>
```

How can I solve this thing?

Comment: disabled input data are not submitted, make sure `$("#BtnSubmit").attr("disabled", true);` does not unintentionally restricting the command value posting

Comment: Are you also submitting the form using ajax?

Comment: No, the reason is I need to validate the form before submitted

Answer (score 0):

End up I adding new input and modified script in the jQuery and is working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#BtnSubmit").click(function(){

            var input = $("<input>")
               .attr("type", "hidden")
               .attr("name", "Command").val("Submit");

            $('#formAssign').append($(input));


            if ($('#formAssign').valid()) {

                var l = $('#BtnSubmit').ladda();

                l.ladda('start');

                $("#BtnApp").attr("disabled", true);

                $('#formAssign').submit();
            }
        });

        $("#BtnApp").click(function(){

            var input = $("<input>")
                        .attr("type", "hidden")
                        .attr("name", "Command").val("Approved");
            $('#formAssign').append($(input));

            if ($('#formAssign').valid()) {



                var l = $('#BtnApp').ladda();

                l.ladda('start');

                $("#BtnSubmit").attr("disabled", true);

                $('#formAssign').submit();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```